# Basic manipulation of a table in R

Tags: r

This is pretty staright forward but I don't seem how I can do this in R, mostly because of my severely limitted exposure to the language

So I have a table, which is kind of a singularity matrix: 
It is of the form:

```
rownames    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1          0   1   0   1
R2          0   1   1   0
R3          1   0   1   0
R4          0   0   0   0
```

So I want to plot this in a mening ful manner,one way I found is if I change the matrix to  show the rownames themselves in the data ,

so at place in the table where there is '1', I want to replace it by the respective rowname

So what I want to do is this:

```
rownames    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1          0   R1  0   R1
R2          0   R2  R2  0
R3          R3  0   R3  0
R4          0   0   0   0
```

I realize this is something really simple, but I find R language little difficult to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these actual row names or a column that called that way?

Comment: No that is just an example, the actual rownames are something like  'Attachment', 'Affected User'

And column name would be like  'INC-Request for hardware'

Comment: Assuming that `rownames` is a column, `t(apply(d,1,function(rw) {rw[rw==1] <- rw[1]; rw}))`

Comment: Great!! It seems to work, you can add your answer in the answers so I can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rownames` is a column, you can do:

```
t(apply(d,1,function(rw) {rw[rw==1] <- rw[1]; rw}))
```

which will scan the data frame row by row and replace `1` by the corresponding value from the first column.

`d` is the initial data set:

```
    d <- structure(list(rownames = structure(1:4, .Label = c("R1", "R2", 
"R3", "R4"), class = "factor"), C1 = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), C2 = c(1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L), C3 = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 0L), C4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("rownames", 
"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible vectorized solution

```
indx <- which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
df[indx[order(indx[, 1]), ]] <- rep(row.names(df), rowSums(df))
#    C1 C2 C3 C4
# R1  0 R1  0 R1
# R2  0 R2 R2  0
# R3 R3  0 R3  0
# R4  0  0  0  0
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), C2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    C3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), C4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("R1", 
"R2", "R3", "R4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-structure(list(C1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), C2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    C3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), C4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4"), row.names = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"), class = "data.frame")

   for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
        df[df[,i]==1,i]<-row.names(df)[which(df[,i]==1)] 
        }
    > df
       C1 C2 C3 C4
    R1  0 R1  0 R1
    R2  0 R2 R2  0
    R3 R3  0 R3  0
    R4  0  0  0  0
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also try (using @David Arenburg's data)

```
df[!!df] <- rownames(df)[row(df)*!!df]
df
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
#R1  0 R1  0 R1
#R2  0 R2 R2  0
#R3 R3  0 R3  0
#R4  0  0  0  0
```